# Power BI: How to make a measure grouped off of another column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am just starting out with Power BI and having the most frustrating time trying to figure out this issue.

Here is a very small example of the data I pull in from an Excel file. Cannot get it any other way.

`╔══════════════╦══════════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════════════╗
║ Product Type ║   Product Name   ║ Dollar Sales  ║ Product Share of Type ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════════════╣
║ Bagels       ║ Client 1 Bagels  ║    $15,521.09 ║  2.42                 ║
║ Bagels       ║ Client 2 Bagels  ║   $112,059.11 ║ 17.46                 ║
║ Muffins      ║ Client 1 Muffins ║   $141,417.84 ║  3.25                 ║
║ Muffins      ║ Client 2 Muffins ║ $1,483,643.52 ║ 34.11                 ║
║ Muffins      ║ Client 3 Muffins ║    $19,008.64 ║  0.44                 ║
║ Pies         ║ Client 2 Pies    ║ $1,718,242.24 ║ 43.90                 ║
║ Pies         ║ Client 3 Pies    ║    $39,883.20 ║  1.02                 ║
║ Pies         ║ Client 4 Pies    ║   $282,140.64 ║  7.21                 ║
╚══════════════╩══════════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════════════╝`

I do not have all Bagel products, just a select few that I do work with. Same for the other products in this data set.

So if I want to calculate what the total dollar sales of all Bagel Type products are, I can get pretty close with what I have available.

I can calculate the total Dollar sales of Type by making a calculated column of `Dollar Sales/(Product Share of Type/100)`. Example Results:

`╔══════════════╦══════════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ Product Type ║   Product Name   ║ Type Total Dollars ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║ Bagels       ║ Client 1 Bagels  ║   $641,367.36      ║
║ Bagels       ║ Client 2 Bagels  ║   $641,804.75      ║
║ Muffins      ║ Client 1 Muffins ║ $4,351,318.15      ║
║ Muffins      ║ Client 2 Muffins ║ $4,349,585.22      ║
║ Muffins      ║ Client 3 Muffins ║ $4,320,145.45      ║
║ Pies         ║ Client 2 Pies    ║ $3,913,991.44      ║
║ Pies         ║ Client 3 Pies    ║ $3,910,117.65      ║
║ Pies         ║ Client 4 Pies    ║ $3,913,185.02      ║
╚══════════════╩══════════════════╩════════════════════╝`

In bagels, we get:

- $641,367.36 Total Type Dollars for `Client 1 Bagels`
- $641,804.75 Total Type Dollars for `Client 2 Bagels`
- This gives a very small difference of $437.39.

The small differences don't really worry me.

The problem is the result is calculated for each row (because I used the calculated column, and I don't know another way). If I turn around and want to get a total of all Type dollars, then the values are getting counted for each record. This will double, triple, quadruple, etc. based off of how ever many product items I have in my data set.

In the case of bagels:

- $1,283,172.11 Total Type Dollars
- This is basically a double count

So how can I create a measure that takes into account another column?

If I were to sum(Dollar Sales) for Product Type, and sum(Product Share of Type) for Product Type, it would be that much more accurate, and I wouldn't be double counting the finished value.

(I don't need the table as an output, I just need a measure that would give me the same results as the final column if I were to create a matrix piece with Power PI):

`╔══════════════╦═══════════════════╦════════════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ Product Type ║ Sum(Dollar Sales) ║ Sum(Share of Type) ║ Type Total Dollars ║
╠══════════════╬═══════════════════╬════════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║ Bagels       ║   $127,580.20     ║ 19.88              ║   $641,751.51      ║
║ Muffins      ║ $1,644,070.00     ║ 37.80              ║ $4,349,391.53      ║
║ Pies         ║ $2,040,266.08     ║ 52.13              ║ $3,990,535.35      ║
╚══════════════╩═══════════════════╩════════════════════╩════════════════════╝`

I have tried `CALCULATE()` and `SUMX()` but I still cannot seem to get subtotals based off of product type before making the final calculation.

I did try creating a `GROUPBY()` table of values, but then the problem is I cannot have those results in the same table/graph as the other results because filters don't apply (I'm running basically everything from this one data set/table).

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TotalSales := CALCULATE(SUM(TableName[Dollar Sales]),
                        All(TableName[Product Name]
                       )
```

What you're doing with that formula is ignoring any filters imposed by the PivotTable on the *Product Name* column, therefore it will give you the total for any other field that you place in the Pivot. Therefore, if you create a PivotTable with *Product Type* and *Product Name* in the row labels, it will give you the total by Product Type.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Somewhat. Like I said, I am quite new to Power BI. So when you're talking about creating a PivotTable, do I need to do that in my Data View, in order to have the proper values to create graphs in my Report View?

If so, how do I make both tables of data filter on the same info? When I tried that previously, I couldn't link a relationship to like columns and treat them as filters.